# How to split a file based on new line and get just the second field in a file after splitting

Tags: awk

Sample text file below:

```
#This is a sample file

## version 3.0 
- change 1 
- change 2

## version 2.5
- change 1
- change 2
- change 3

## version 2.4
- change 1
- change 2
```

I'm only after the latest changes in this file which is at the top as below.

```
## version 3.0 
- change 1 
- change 2
```

I'm able to create the following command:

```
awk -v RS= '{print > ("filename" NR ".txt")}' sample.txt
```

But i don't want to create all the file. Just one while with the content i need.

Comment: Is `#this is a sample file` exist for real in the file?

Comment: Yes. There would be some other text. I've provided a sample here

Comment: Do you have one liner for this? Why i try it gives me the first version information at the bottom of the file not the latest which is at the top of the file

Comment: I would note that this is Markdown. and use a Markdown parser

Comment: Regarding "Do you have one liner for this?" - that tells us you favor brevity over clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability and everything else that actually matters in software and so discourages people from answering as it suggests you'll reject a good answer in favor of a brief one. SO you may not want to ask for a "one liner". You can always cram any program onto 1 line once you get a good answer if that matters to you for some reason.

Comment: You say "I'm only after the latest changes in this file" and then show that the expected output is for `version 3.0` - is that because that block is the first one in the file or because it's version number is highest or something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: If first block is the desired output, then  `awk '/# version/{a=NR};a && (!NF || !a){exit}a'` should do.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with `\n\n` support as `R`ecord `S`eparator and `gensub()`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}
    {
        v=gensub(/## version ([0-9\.]+)/, "\\1", "1")
        v=v+0      # numeric cast
        if (v > max) {
            max=v
            arr[v]=$0
        }
    }
    END{print arr[max]}
' file
```

```
## version 3.0 
- change 1 
- change 2
```

---

[image: note]
the block can be anywhere in the input. This solution don't rely on the order of blocks

Comment: Thanks, fixed my post.

Comment: You're welcome. That still wouldn't work for a version number like `3.5.1` though. I know the OP only showed 2-number versions but 3-number are very common for `major.minor.patch`, etc. versioning. FWIW splitting it on `.`s and then looping saving to a string using `sprintf("%03s",a[i])` to convert `3.5.1` to `003005001` (or similar) and then comparing that as a string is probably adequate.

Comment: Very clever idea. Up to OP for the records

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/\n-/{print; exit}' sample.txt
## version 3.0
- change 1
- change 2
```

just redirect that output to a file, there's no reason to have awk spawn a subshell to create the output file as you're doing in the code in your question, just let the shell do it when you call awk:

```
awk -v RS= '/\n-/{print; exit}' sample.txt > output.txt
```

Change `/\n-/` to `/^## version/` or `NR > 1` or whatever you need to identify a version block separately from leading comments if `/\n-/` isn't adequate.

Comment: Upvoted. Better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is allowed (portability):

```
perl -00 -ne '
    BEGIN{our $max = 0, %h}
    my ($v) = /## version ([\d\.]+)/;
    if ($v > $max) {$max=$v; $h{$v}=$_}
    END{print $h{$max}}
' file
```

the block can be anywhere in the input.